# Does attr_accessible create getters and setters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does attr_accessible create getters and setters?

I keep reading that attr_accessible and attr_accessor are different.
But in my code base I keep seeing people write:

```
attr_accessor :email
attr_accessible :email
```

And this seems odd.
Does attr_accessible not create getters and setters?

For rails 4, I know to use strong parameters, so is it best to only use attr_accessor?

Edit: I've seen this posted on SO many times:

> attr_accessor makes getters and setters while attr_accessible allows
>   to pass values in a mass assignment.

I'm more looking for a 'Yes' or 'No' to my question. If the answer is No, does rails automatically create getters and setters for columns in your database?

Edit: so I think I get it now.

```
attr_accessor :email
attr_accessible :email
```

Doing the above, would allow you to mass-assign a virtual property that would not be saved to the database. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_accessible` does not create accessors.

Activerecord generates accessors for database columns automatically. `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected` just control whether they will be invoked from methods such as `update_attributes` (And can be use with any accessor methods, not just ones backed by database columns)

Answer (score 0):

**YES**
`attr_accessible` create getters and setters.

`attr_accessible` is normally used for models with corresponding tables while `attr_accessor` for models with no corresponding database tables.

Comment: Ok, I keep seeing this answer, but that is not the answer to my question. Are you saying that, no, attr_accessible does not create getters and setters?

Comment: @EricFrancis, made a deeper expanation from my point of view and how i use them differently!

Comment: Thank your for your edit. So does attr_accessible create getters and setters for columns in your database?